# Mysql select first then limit

Tags: mysql

How can i select the newest 5 rows from mysql (newest by id for example) then order them asc or desc ??

the problem is i have 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 , i want to select the newest 2 for example (6,7) then order them asc or desc (6,7 or 7,6) , but if i use the orderby then the limit it would be (1,2) or (7,6) , is there anyway to do it from ONE sql statement ?

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select * from TABLE order by id asc , time_stamp desc
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use something like

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM TABLE WHERE X ORDER BY ID LIMIT 2) ORDER BY ID DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get if you wanted the newest 5 or 2, I use 2 here. But here is something I just wrote without testing.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2) ORDER BY id ASC/DESC;
```

Hope this will help! :)

Answer (score 0):

ok i found the solution , thank you all for your efforts and answers ,

i made 2 columns , ID and TSTAMP (for timestamp) , just made it like order by id asc , tstamp asc/desc ... limit x , so it orders always by the id then orders by the tstamp and limits the right thing .

and nested queries are a pain for the engine ...

thanks

Answer (score -1):

Why can't you do something such as

```
SELECT *
FROM   TABLE
WHERE (TABLE.primary_key IN (
  SELECT   TABLE.primary_key
  FROM     TABLE
  ORDER BY TABLE.id ASC
  LIMIT    2
))
ORDER BY TABLE.id DESC
```